# Speed php getmxrr() function for processing million records

Tags: php, performance, mx-record

I have a code where i am getting the domains from the database and passing them through the PHP getmxrr function. Then I am storing the results in the database. But the process is very slow. Is there any way to speed the things up?

```
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($row as $value) {
    $domain = $value[0];

    //getmxrr doesn't work without this
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$domain); 

    if (getmxrr($string,$mxrecords)){        

        if(isset($mxrecords[0])){
        $mx = $mxrecords[0];} else $mx = "False";
    }
    else{
        $mx = "NULL";
    }
    $stmt1->execute();    //inserting the results in DB

}
```

Comment: How many records are you processing? and could you define "slow", and are you sure it isn't the mysql that is slow?

Comment: I assume the problem is the duration of the DNS request. Try to use a different (better caching) DNS servers to speed up reoccurring requests.

Comment: From slow i mean around 1-2 requests per second. @RyanNaddy

Comment: @Stasik right assumption. How to do that?

Comment: @user2419169 what DNS are you using? Firstly, try to change your OS' DNS server to some others, maybe Google ones (8.8.8.8)? Next step is to get an own DNS cache, it depends on OS (e.g. for Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/22750/best-way-to-set-up-dns-caching).

Comment: just how many dns lookups are you performing? try to get MX records for the entire 32bit IPv4 space?

Comment: i performed for 500 (took 300 seconds) and for 3000 (took 1800 approx)

Comment: @Stasik I am using google DNS.

Comment: @user2419169 than try a local ISP, or better bind9, pdnsd, or dnsmasq as stated in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is the duration of the DNS request. Try to use a different (better caching) DNS servers to speed up reoccurring requests.

Firstly, try to change your OS' DNS server to some others, maybe Google ones (8.8.8.8)? Next step is to get an own DNS cache, it depends on OS (e.g. for Ubuntu/Linux https://askubuntu.com/questions/22750/best-way-to-set-up-dns-caching).